# count 45 Working days after a selected date in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have one date parameter. 31 October 2014. i want to get next days = 45 days after 31 October 2014. So it should be 2 Januari 2015. and **excluding Saturday and Sunday**.

I already make the function like this. But when i add 45. the 45 not excluding Saturday and Sunday.

```
function getNextBusinessDay() {
    return getDeliveryDateObj(1);
}
function getDeliveryDateObj(businessDaysLeftForDelivery) {
    var now = new Date();
    var dayOfTheWeek = now.getDay();
    now.setDate(now.getDate() + 45);

    var calendarDays = businessDaysLeftForDelivery;
    var deliveryDay = dayOfTheWeek + businessDaysLeftForDelivery;
    if (deliveryDay >= 6) {
        businessDaysLeftForDelivery -= 6 - dayOfTheWeek;  //deduct this-week days
        calendarDays += 2;  //count this coming weekend
        deliveryWeeks = Math.floor(businessDaysLeftForDelivery / 5); //how many whole weeks?
        calendarDays += (deliveryWeeks * 2);  //two days per weekend per week
    }
    now.setTime(now.getTime() + calendarDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    return now;
}
```

Comment: Try adding 63 instead. 45 days excluding saturday/sunday is exactly 9 weeks, which is 63 days including saturday/sunday. Of course, that does not take any other holidays into account.

Comment: you have not written anything in your code to exclude sat & sund

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved my problem:

```
function test() {
    var startDate = "31-oct-2014";
    startDate = new Date(startDate.replace(/-/g, "/"));
    var endDate = "", noOfDaysToAdd = 45, count = 0;
    while (count < noOfDaysToAdd) {
        endDate = new Date(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1));
        if (endDate.getDay() != 0 && endDate.getDay() != 6) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    $("#Test").val(endDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This `addWeekdays` function should do what you want.

```js
function addWeekdays(date, weekdays) {
  var newDate = new Date(date.getTime());
  var i = 0;
  while (i < weekdays) {
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
    var day = newDate.getDay();
    if (day > 1 && day < 7) {
      i++;
    }
  }
  return newDate;
}

var currentDate = new Date('10/31/2014');
var targetDate = addWeekdays(currentDate, 45);
alert(targetDate);
```